# Unable to ping 8.8.8.8 when connecting ubuntu PCs via ethernet

Tags: networking, dns, ethernet

I'm currently using jetson-nano, which doesn't have a lan card built in. My only choice now is to connect via ethernet and I'm having difficulty connecting it. As a beginner, I've had many trials and I some how managed to ping ip from wireless LAN in ubuntu PC I'm connecting to. But pinging DNS server 8.8.8.8 didn't work. DNS like google.com doesn't work either. I would really appreciate it if the explanation is detailed. Thank you.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.137.2
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.137.1
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
     dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4
     dns-search google.com
     dns-domain google.com
up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.137.1
up route add -net 8.8.8.8 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.137.1
```

---

- ping 192.168.137.1 worked,
- ping 192.168.0.71 worked,
- ping 8.8.8.8 did not work,
- ping google.com did not work either.

[image: picture of a routing table]

Comment: I'm not sure why the words got jammed together. contents from address to dns-domain are tabbed under eth0. up routes are dependently written.

Comment: Also I'm not sure it might help, but there are two lights in ethernet connection in jetson nano board, and green light is turned on and the orange light blinks.